# Whose password should I enter?

Tags: fedora, gnome, root, password, mate-desktop

> Authentication is required to perform this action.

Whose password should I enter? Mine? Root's? I can never tell.

[image: ss of dialog]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yours. What you are looking at is a `gksudo` window. It is the same thing as `sudo`, a program that allows you to run things with root privileges by entering *your* password.

Comment: I understand the rules "if you ran `su` then type root's password" and 'if you ran `sudo` then type your own password' but I didn't [explicitly] run either! I just tried to open something from the menu. How can you tell `gksudo` apart from its twin `gksu`?

Comment: @ColonelPanic on most systems (at least debian ones) `gksudo` is actually a link to `gksu`. Anyway, if you're asked for root's password that will be made clear to you. If you are asked for a password with no more info, then 99% of the times, you should enter you user's password.

Answer (score 1):

In Fedora, chances are that the password this dialog is asking for is indeed your own user password. However, in the ecosystem of Linux and Unix, **this is not always true**.

`gksu` and `gksudo` are a GUI front-end to `sudo`, which in turn pays attention to `/etc/sudoers`. Adding `rootpw` as a parameter to a user, group, or a default definition in `/etc/sudoers` will require the root password entered for that user, group, or by default in all of the above sudo's, unless otherwise overridden. See https://superuser.com/questions/161593/how-do-i-make-sudo-ask-for-the-root-password for more info.

While this is not the default for most Linux distributions (I can't speak for Unix much), I seem to remember that it was at least, for a time, the default in OpenSuSE. This was one of the very first things I disabled when doing a new install.